# How to cumulatively update a dictionary with values from other dictionaries?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a master dictionary to keep the word frequency of the entire corpus and individual dictionaries to keep the word frequency for each text file. I loop over each file, generate the WF of each file, and sequentially update the master dictionary. My code is as follows. Is there a shortcut?  Thank you!

```
 master_dict = {}
 for txtfile in txtfiles:
    file_dict = {}
    file_dict = get_word_freq(txtfile) #A function is defined
    for k, v in file_dict.items():
        if k in master_dict:
             master_dict[k] += v
        else:
             master_dict[K] = v
```

Comment: I did - but misread the `+=` line, thanks for pointing that out. (removed my comment to avoid confusion)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should consider using the 'Counter' class that python has.

```py
from collections import Counter

words_a = 'one two three'
words_b = 'one two one two'
words_c = 'three four five'

a = Counter(words_a.split())
b = Counter(words_b.split())
c = Counter(words_c.split())

print(a + b + c)
# outputs Counter({'one': 3, 'two': 3, 'three': 2, 'four': 1, 'five': 1})
```